# Progress 4gl como deshabilitar el botón de cerrar una pantalla

Tags: botón, progressbar, dialog, progressdialog, progress

Necesito deshabilitar un botón de cerrar la pantalla en progress 4gl para que se tenga que usar un botón o otro para salir de la pantalla
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6cxM.png)

Necesito que se haga así porque sino las validaciones de los botones no se hacen, y se pierde la modificaciones o se aplican.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de encontrar la solución gracias a un compañero de trabajo, para ello hace falta añadir al Main Block esta parte de código, esto hace que la pantalla deshabilite el la X de pantalla.
Este código hay que incrustarlo en en Main Block de la aplicación, de este modo la pantalla no hará ninguna acción al presionar el botón x de la misma.

```
on window-close of frame {&frame-name} do:
    return no-apply.
end.
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).